# initializer_list constructor somehow excluded from std::variant constructor overload set

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list, variant, constructor-overloading

Help me solve this puzzle: In the following code I have an `std::variant` which forward declares a struct proxy which derives from this variant. This struct is only used because recursive `using`  declarations are afaik not a thing in C++ (unfortunately). Anyway, I pull in all the base class constructors of the variant which define for each declared variant alternative T

```
template< class T >
constexpr variant( T&& t ) noexcept(/* see below */);
```

according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant). I would assume that this means that a constructor for `std::initializer_list<struct proxy>` as type T is also defined. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. The following code results in an error:

```
#include <variant>

using val = std::variant<std::monostate, int, double, std::initializer_list<struct proxy>>;

struct proxy : val
{
    using val::variant;
};

int main()
{
    proxy some_obj = {1,2,3,2.5,{1,2}};
}
```

[CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%0Ausing+val+%3D+std::variant%3Cstd::monostate,+int,+double,+std::initializer_list%3Cstruct+proxy%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Astruct+proxy+:+val%0A%7B%0A++++using+val::variant%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++proxy+some_obj+%3D+%7B1,2,3,2.5,%7B1,2%7D%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Clang Error (because gcc doesn't go into much detail):

```
<source>:12:11: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'proxy'
    proxy some_obj = {1,2,3,2.5,{1,2}};
          ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/variant:1434:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'in_place_type_t<_Tp>' against 'int'
        variant(in_place_type_t<_Tp>, initializer_list<_Up> __il,
        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/variant:1455:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'in_place_index_t<_Np>' against 'int'
        variant(in_place_index_t<_Np>, initializer_list<_Up> __il,
        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/variant:1424:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'in_place_type_t<_Tp>' against 'int'
        variant(in_place_type_t<_Tp>, _Args&&... __args)
        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/variant:1444:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'in_place_index_t<_Np>' against 'int'
        variant(in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&&... __args)
        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/variant:1401:7: note: candidate inherited constructor not viable: requires single argument '__rhs', but 5 arguments were provided
      variant(const variant& __rhs) = default;
```

What I get from this is that the above mentioned constructor taking the variant alternatives T is not considered. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `proxy` class does not have a declared constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list<proxy>`.  What it has, is a constructor *template* that accepts any type, `T`.  But for that template to be chosen, the compiler has to deduce the type of `T`.  The *braced-init-list* `{1,2,3,2.5,{1,2}}` does not have any inherent type though, so the compiler can't deduce the type `T`.

It's easy to think that a *braced-init-list* **is** a `std::initializer_list`, but that is not the case.  There are some special cases where a `std::initializer_list` will be implicitly constructed from a *braced-init-list*, but deducing a template type parameter is not one of those cases.

You *could* explicitly construct a `std::initializer_list<proxy>`, i.e.

```
proxy some_obj = std::initializer_list<proxy>{1,2,3,2.5,std::initializer_list<proxy>{1,2}};
```

But keep in mind that `std::initializer_list` only holds *pointers* to its elements, and it does not extend their lifetimes.  All of those `proxy` objects will go out of scope at the end of the full expression, and `some_obj` will immediately be holding a `std::initializer_list` full of dangling pointers.  If you need a recursive type, you will almost certainly need to dynamically allocate the recursive children (and remember to clean them up, as well).  `std::initializer_list` is not sufficient for this use case.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! I thought that the list is converted to an initializer_list first and then a suitable constructor is instantiated. But it makes sense that the list is only converted to an initializer_list in case there is an appropriate constructor.